# iOS - Get list of available WiFi Networks

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin.ios, wifi

Good morning,

We have a IoT device, that we have no way of changing. This device has the ability to be put into a broadcast mode which turns the device into a Wifi Router that we connect to. Once we are connected to the device, we then have the ability to set that device up to connect to a customer's WiFi network.

What I’m wanting to do is this:

1. User will physically put the device in broadcast mode
2. Mobile app will then scan all available local wifi’s looking for a SSID that matches the a MAC Address 3: The mobile app will then need to connect the device to the consumer's WiFi.

#2 is where the problem lies. I need to get a list of wifi networks local to the mobile device so I can pick out the MAC address that I need to connect to.

Any examples of this working would be awesome. The application I'm writing is written in Xamarin.

Thanks,

I've tried getting access to the HotSpotHelper API from Apple but they have declined my request.  I'm not sure how else to go about this.

I'm looking for a .Net Xamarin example to get this to work.